# Coerce character variable into numeric without warnings

Tags: r, class, apply

I'm fairly new to R and I'm encountering a problem in one of my functions. I want to convert three of the columns in a data.frame from character to numeric. They are mostly made up of numbers with a few "Not Available" entries scattered throughout. I am aware of these, and I want them coerced to NAs without seeing the warning, so I'm using the `suppressWarnings()` function.

Here is my code:

```
suppressWarnings(class(dataframe[,2]) <- "numeric")
suppressWarnings(class(dataframe[,3]) <- "numeric")
suppressWarnings(class(dataframe[,4]) <- "numeric")
print(apply(dataframe,2,class))
```

My issue is that the result that gets printed is:

```
          1           2           3           4 
"character" "character" "character" "character"
```

So it doesn't seem to be changing the class! Why is this?

When I do it without suppressing the warnings, like this:

```
  class(dataframe[,2]) <- "numeric"
  class(dataframe[,3]) <- "numeric"
  class(dataframe[,4]) <- "numeric"
  print(apply(dataframe,2,class))
```

I get the same output, but with the warning message:

```
          1           2           3           4 
"character" "character" "character" "character" 
Warning messages:
1: In class(dataframe[, 2]) <- "numeric" : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In class(dataframe[, 3]) <- "numeric" : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In class(dataframe[, 4]) <- "numeric" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

So it's not the warning suppression that's the problem. It must be the `apply()` function, but I can't figure out why it would display the classes incorrectly.

Any advice or assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried `dataframe[,2] <- as.numeric(dataframe[,2])`?

Comment: I did try that, and I got the same output.

Comment: can you paste a `dput(dataframe)` output (or even an extended `head` of `dataframe`)?

Comment: The actual data in question have 40+ variables and contain confidential information, so I can't post any of it... I do know that the columns I'm trying to coerce only contain numbers or "Not Available" entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `apply`; see "Details" in `?apply`: "If X is not an array [..], `apply` attempts to coerce it to an array via `as.matrix` if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame)." Then have a look at "Details in `?as.matrix`: "The method for data frames will return a character matrix if there is only atomic columns and any non-(numeric/logical/complex) column". Thus, despite that your conversion to numeric works, the use of `apply` to 'loop' over columns when checking their class first coerces the data frame to a character matrix.

A small example. First create a toy data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "b"),
                 x2 = c("Not Available", 2),
                 x3 = c("Not Available", 3),
                 x4 = c(4, "Not available"))
```

Convert selected columns to numeric as you did in you question, or like this:

```
df[, 2:4] <- lapply(df[ , 2:4], function(x) as.numeric(x))
str(df)
```

If the resulting data frame is coerced to a matrix, as `apply` would do, it is coerced to a character matrix

```
str(as.matrix(df))
# chr [1:2, 1:4] "a" "b" NA " 2" NA " 3" " 4" NA
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# ..$ : NULL
# ..$ : chr [1:4] "x1" "x2" "x3" "x4"
```

Instead of using `apply`to check the class of your columns, you may try:

```
sapply(df, class)
#          x1          x2          x3          x4 
# "character"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric" 

str(df)
# 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ x1: chr  "a" "b"
# $ x2: num  NA 2
# $ x3: num  NA 3
# $ x4: num  4 NA
```